# Browser SecurityPolicyViolation event not firing when cache is disabled

Tags: javascript, browser, browser-cache, content-security-policy

Strange behavior alert.
We're working on trying to get content security policy violations logged to our server and block the user from further interaction when this happens. In order to do this, we are listening to the `securitypolicyviolation` event the browser throws whenever a CSP violation happens. That is all working fine, especially when we block a script from being run from some kind of injection.
Here's the funky part. When we try to block domains, everything is in fact blocked correctly. HOWEVER, when we have our cache disabled (when the browser inspector is open, there's an option to disable cache), the browser still blocks the domain, but no violation is thrown.

Here is how we are listening to the violation:

```js
document.addEventListener('securitypolicyviolation', (e) => {
   console.log(e)
   ...
}
```

Here is what we have in our test file:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="module" src="https://ghcdn.rawgit.org/AStoker/CSP_Experiments/main/nefarious.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Nefarious Form</h1>
        <input id="nefarious" />
    </body>
</html>
```

This allows us to test a trusted domain (`rawgit.org`) loading up a file from an untrusted domain (`cloudflare.com`).
As a note, here is our header for the CSP rule:

```
content-security-policy: script-src 'self' 'sha256-F3K/CgXTTxIkyajbxetrCJ4U5o7hfSnOpfrJI3KA9AA='  'unsafe-eval' https://ghcdn.rawgit.org; child-src 'none'
```

So what ends up happening is when the page is loaded, we correctly get the **browser behavior** of blocking, but don't get our **browser event** notifying us that something happened.

> Refused to load the script 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.5.1/knockout-latest.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'sha256-F3K/CgXTTxIkyajbxetrCJ4U5o7hfSnOpfrJI3KA9AA='  'unsafe-eval' https://ghcdn.rawgit.org". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

So, the question is, why is disabling browser cache causing the browser to not throw a security policy violation?

Comment: Strange, but my event is [triggered](https://csplite.com/csp/test354/), Chrome v87.0.4280.141. Maybe it's some settings at `chrome://flags` interfere? Can you check in different Chrome/PC?

Comment: @granty, we've tested across almost all browsers on two different machines. Safari, Chrome, and Edge on Mac, and Chrome, Edge, and Firefox on a PC. All exhibiting the same strange behavior. We noticed that after disabling cache in the web inspector tools, you sometimes had to refresh the browser twice (it would start to fail on the second refresh). Similarly, to get it to work, after re-enabling cache in the web inspector tools, it would take two refreshes for it to correctly throw the error again.

Comment: Yes, after enabling / disabling the cache, sometimes you need to refresh browser again to get reports of violations.

Comment: @granty, do you happen to know why? That seems like a fairly strange requirement browsers would have.

Comment: Browser local caching is a mystery. But in your case different browsers behave the same. Perhaps the caching of the ISP in the middle is interfering. I noticed that after changing the rules of the Content Security Policy HTTP header, for about 2 weeks, reports of violations with the old policy continue to come. Since the site does not have a core of regular visitors, it means that some ISPs(mostly mobile) forcely cache pages.